# Not understanding how to solve this question?

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z=x+iy$ lies in the third quadrant, then prove that $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ also lies in the third quadrant when $y<x<0$.

**My attempt:**  I got equation $$\frac{x^2 - y^2 - 2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$

Now , I got $x^2 - y^2<0 $ and $-2xy<0$ , $x^2 < y ^2$. Therefore $y$ is greater than $x$. I got $y<x$ this I did not get.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, how did you get $x^2-y^2<0$ if you didn't assume the inequality $y<x<0$? You can only get that if you assume $y<x<0$ because that would imply $|y|>|x|$ hence $y^2>x^2$.

Comment: Pls check the edit

Comment: It didn't make any difference. My point still remains same.

Comment: Ohk.yes.I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\frac{\bar z}z=\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}=\frac{x^2-y^2-2xyi}{x^2+y^2}\,,$$

with real part $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ and imaginary part $-2xy$. You seem to have got that far just fine.

You’re **given** that $y<x<0$: it’s not something that you have to prove or discover. That implies that $y^2>x^2$, so $x^2-y^2<0$. Moreover, $x^2+y^2>0$, so $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}<0$: that shows that the real part is negative. Finally, $x$ and $y$ are negative, so $xy>0$, and $-2xy<0$: that shows that the imaginary part is also negative. And that puts $\frac{\bar z}z$ in the third quadrant.

Note that $y^2>x^2$ does **not** imply that $y>x$: it implies only that $|y|>|x|$. And when $x$ and $y$ are negative, as is the case here, that means that $y<x$.

Comment: If x > y . Then x^2 - y^2 has to be a positive value which is not greater than right.How is it possible that y <x but y ^2>x^2 ?

Comment: Is it that can be y could be negative at that point but when squared became + and had more value than x ^2

Comment: Ok.I got it know .

Comment: @user282657: Just to be sure, you might think about a specific example, say $y=-2$ and $x=-1$: then $x^2=1<4=y^2$, but $y<x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y>x>0$ and $z=-x-iy$ which is in the third quadrant since $-y<-x<0$, then
$$w=\frac{\bar{z}}{z}=\frac{-x+iy}{-x-iy}=\frac{-x+iy}{-x-iy}\frac{-x+iy}{-x+iy}=\frac{x^2-y^2-2ixy}{x^2+y^2}.$$
Since $y>x>0$ then $x^2-y^2<0$ and $-2xy<0$ and $w$ is in the third quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), we have that for $z = re^{i \theta}$:

$$\frac{\bar{z}}{z} = \frac{re^{-i \theta}}{re^{i \theta}} = e^{-2 i \theta} = \cos(-2 \theta)+i\sin(-2\theta).$$

$z$ lies in the third quadrant, hence $\pi < \theta < 3 \pi/2$. $y < x < 0$ restricts this to $5 \pi / 4 < \theta < 3 \pi/2$ (sketch this).

This means $-3 \pi < -2\theta < -5 \pi/2$ (do each inequality separately), or adding $4 \pi$ to both sides, $\pi < -2 \theta < \frac{3 \pi}{2}$. Hence $\bar{z}/z$ also lies in the third quadrant.

Comment: To the OP: don't worry if you haven't learnt this yet.